# How to create dynamic sql query in pentaho report designer PRD 5.3?

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-design-studio, pentaho-ctools

I am using petaho report desiner

My main query is

```
select create_date  , sum(product_uos_qty) from sale_order_line group
by create_date
```

It is running properly

and sub query is

```
SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='public' 
 AND table_name='sale_order_line' 
 AND (column_name = 'product_uos_qty' OR column_name ='price_unit')
```

output of this query is

```
product_uos_qty
price_unit
```

I create a parameter select

and convert main query into this

```
select create_date  , sum(${select}) from sale_order_line group by create_date
```

but it is not running it gives following error

> ERROR: The query 'main' did not execute successfully. The reason given
>   was:
>   'org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException:
>   Failed at query: select create_date  , sum(${select}) from
>   sale_order_line group by create_date'

tell me what is the main problem and how i can solve it

Comment: do you need both `product_uos_qty,price_unit` column in the sub select or what ?

Comment: ya i need both but need one at a time on selection base

Comment: side note: does this `select create_date  , sum(product_uos_qty),sum(price_unit) from sale_order_line group
 by create_date` approach cant be use ?

Comment: I think It can give the access both product_uos_qty and price_unit at the same time

Comment: Need Clarifucation : why you're uisng this `SELECT column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_name='sale_order_line' and (column_name = 'product_uos_qty' or column_name ='price_unit')` ?, you can give the column name directly right?

Comment: yes right ,   but if i give column name directly that will not work in drop down section in pentaho subquery  .   so i use this query which output is input as a main query